# Javascript - Insert string into text at variable locations

Tags: javascript, string, text, replace

I have a large text field stored in a database.  The text field is seeded with variables at specific locations, similar to how console.log() works.

"This text was written by $user1, on $date, while $user1 was working with $user2 to complete the $subject"

Then I could swap out the variables with the correct dynamic values.

Curious if there is a straightforward way to resolve this, or if I'm stuck splitting the string at each location and then rebuilding with the new values.

Comment: how your variables look like? provide the complete strings/variables/data you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `replace` function in javascript, it uses regex.

Example:

```
var user1 = "Joe";
var original = "This text was written by $user1, on $date, while $user1 was working with $user2 to complete the $subject";
var newString = original.replace(/\$user1/g, user1);
```

and so on.

Comment: You're welcome :) Kindly mark it as the answer if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

[String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can be invoked with a `RegExp` for the matching and a function to dynamically determine the replacement string. If you can create an object map that has property names the same as the variables in your format string and values with the replacements themselves, you can replace them all in one pass by using the matched property name to get the corresponding value from the map object.

Something like this:

```js
var format = "This text was written by $user1, on $date, while $user1 was working with $user2 to complete the $subject";

var replacementsMap = {
    user1: "John",
    date: new Date(),
    user2: "Jane",
    subject: "Collaboration Project"
};

var result = format.replace(/\$([a-z]+\d*)/g, function(match, prop) {
    // match => the full string matched by the regex (e.g. $user1, etc)
    // prop => the captured part of the match (i.e. not including the $)
    return replacementsMap[prop];
});

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks Brian